# With Objective-C, how can I animate the frame position of a bottom layer without affecting top layers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have two `UIImageView`'s, one that is a background that should scroll, and one an avatar that should move positions based on user input.

I'm able to move the avatar with no problem, and I'm able to scroll my background when necessary with:

```
CGRect oldPos = _fieldView.frame;
CGRect newPos = CGRectMake(oldPos.origin.x, oldPos.origin.y - 400, oldPos.size.width, oldPos.size.height);


[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [_fieldView setFrame:newPos];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done with animation");
                 }];
```

However, when this `_fieldview` scrolls, my avatar on top of it scrolls with it. How can I move my background image without affecting the other images?

A few other settings that may affect this:

- I've disabled `AutoLayout`
- My background image mode is set to `AspectFill`
- I'm using a storyboard with a single `UIView`

Thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT

The avatar, `runnerView`, is added as a subview of `_fieldView`, with

```
[_fieldView addSubview:_runnerView];
```

Comment: Do you have one UIImageView added to the other?

Comment: Is the avatar a subview of the uiimageview?

Comment: Yes, the avatar is a subview, added with `[_fieldView addSubview:_runnerView];`

Comment: can you provide more detail code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your background scroll image to not be a superview to your avatar, but  sibling view instead.

(Not the best representation, not sure how to make it look better though)

-Main View
--Scroll view
--Avatar

i.e.

```
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.view addSubview:avatarView];
```

not

-Main View
--Scroll view
---Avatar

i.e.

```
[backgroundView addSubview:avatarView];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

If it is required to be a subview, then you will have to move the avatar view an equal and opposite amount so it will stay in the same relative location.

Comment: it is not required to be a subview

Comment: Then the way to go would be to add the avatar and background to the same superview

Comment: That did it, thank you--can't believe I didn't think of that.